# How to limit processes to all but one cpu in Linux

Tags: cpu, cgroups

I want to limit some processes to run on all but one CPU in a machine. I have looked into it and I believe that cgroups could be a viable solution. More specifically using the cpuset property.

However I have been unable to find an example that limits to more than one CPU. How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple cases, you don't cgroups, it is simpler just using the `taskset` command:

```
taskset --cpu-list 1-7 my_command args ...
```

The first cpu core is 0, this omits 0 from the list. To omit some other core you could do something like: `--cpu-list 0,1,3,4,5,6,7`